How to Extend Express Request Interface to Include Mongoose Session in TypeScript?
I'm working on a Node.js project using Express and Mongoose with TypeScript. I need to attach a Mongoose session to each request to manage transactions. However, I'm encountering a TypeScript error saying that the session property does not exist on the Request type.
Error:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/middlewares/sessionMiddleware.ts:10:7 - error TS2339: Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

10   req.session = session;
         ~~~~~~~

Middleware Code:
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const sessionMiddleware = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  
  // Attach the session to the request object
  req.session = session;


  res.on('finish', async () => {
    if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 400) {
      await session.commitTransaction();
    } else {
      await session.abortTransaction();
    }
    session.endSession();
  });
  
  next();
};

export default sessionMiddleware;

What I've Tried:

Creating a Custom Type Declaration:
I created a custom type declaration file to extend the Request interface:


// types/express.d.ts
import { Session } from 'mongoose';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      session?: Session;
    }
  }
}



Updating tsconfig.json:
I added the custom types to the tsconfig.json file:


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"]
  }
}


Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the same TypeScript error. Can someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong and how to properly extend the Express Request interface to include the session property for Mongoose transactions?
